# Resolv.conf is out of control

Tags: netplan, resolv.conf, systemd-resolved

I have tried God knows how many ways to resolve this and get it under control, but, it doesnt seem to take.  I only want the single nameserver in there as 10.0.0.8. Can someone please help.

I have tried removing the existing /etc/resolv.conf, creating a new one with a single entry, and symlinking followed by reboot to no success.

/etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 10.0.0.8
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 45.90.28.221
# Too many DNS servers configured, the following entries may be ignored.
nameserver 45.90.30.221
nameserver 10.0.0.8
search .
```

/etc/systemd/resolved.conf

```
[Resolve]
# Some examples of DNS servers which may be used for DNS= and FallbackDNS=:
# Cloudflare: 1.1.1.1#cloudflare-dns.com 1.0.0.1#cloudflare-dns.com 2606:4700:4700::1111#cloudflare-dns.com 2606:4700:4700::1001#cloudflare-dns.com
# Google:     8.8.8.8#dns.google 8.8.4.4#dns.google 2001:4860:4860::8888#dns.google 2001:4860:4860::8844#dns.google
# Quad9:      9.9.9.9#dns.quad9.net 149.112.112.112#dns.quad9.net 2620:fe::fe#dns.quad9.net 2620:fe::9#dns.quad9.net
DNS=10.0.0.8
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
#DNSSEC=no
#DNSOverTLS=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#LLMNR=no
```

/etc/netplan/00...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets: #this gets commented out if not using opnsense in virtualbox 
    enp25s0f0:
      dhcp4: no
    enp25s0f1: #comment out if not using opnsense in virtualbox
      dhcp4: no #change from false to true after initial opnsense setup 
  bridges:
    lan1:
      interfaces:
        - enp25s0f0
      addresses: [10.0.0.8/24]
      routes: 
      - to: default
        via: 10.0.0.3
        metric: 100
        on-link: true
#      gateway4: 10.0.0.3
      dhcp4: no
      mtu: 1500
      nameservers:
        addresses: [10.0.0.8]
      parameters: 
        stp: true
        forward-delay: 4
    dmz1:
      interfaces:
        - enp25s0f1
      dhcp4: yes
```

Comment: I did not, and have not, edited /etc/resolv.con, which is part of my frustration.

Comment: interpret however you see fit, im not here to argue I'm simply in search of some assistance

Answer (score 1):

On modern Ubuntu systems (not sure which version you are on, reporting this is best practice in these questions, to clarify) `/etc/resolv.conf` is not meant to be edited directly. This is because these systems run `systemd-resolved` and generate this file dynamically. If you want to change the DNS settings you will either need to use a command-line tool such as `resolvectl` which has a man page that explains how to get or set DNS configuration, or edit certain configuration files, or possibly create them if they do not exist. That command replaced the old `systemd-resolve` command. There is also a shorter summary of how to use the command, running `resolvectl --help` if you don't want to read the whole man page.

If you are on 22.04, you might want to [see this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406827/how-to-set-dns-on-ubuntu-22-04-when-you-have-no-netplan-config) which talks about the relevant configuration file.

Comment: All of this is true, but doesn't explain how or why he has a resolv.conf with 5 DNS server entries. A config file managed by resolved should have a single entry for 127.0.0.1.  Also, if the /etc/resolv.conf symlink isn't pointed to the usual place, that still doesn't explain the 45.x nameservers which don't appear in the posted netplan config.